# Browser shortcut - add url

Tags: javascript

I needed to help with a feature I have never seen before. I do not even know if it exists, but you may have met.
I'm referring to the shortcuts in the browser and I would like to add another shortcut to "add 'this' to the end of the url".
Example:
I am on **www.example.com** and click on the link in the shortcut bar to redirect me to **www.example.com/redir1**. If I'm on **www.example2.com** and click on the same link, it redirects me to **www.example2.com/redir1**.

I manage a number of sites and I have to click on "*Settings/blah blah/page/*" takes a few minutes. By linking, I would like to get straight to the "page" so I do not have to click and load pages before this one so many times.

Comment: @Regolith That is not the purpose of code blocks. Don't abuse it

Answer (score 1):

You may use a **Bookmarklet**.
Bookmarklets are (small) chunks of JavaScript, that will be executed when clicking the bookmarked link. I use them for quick navigation in ticket systems.

Maybe this example solves your problem.
Of course, you have to condense your JavaScript to just one line, so it fits into the address line of the bookmark.

```
javascript:(function(){open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/redir1");})();
```

You can even open a JavaScript prompt for retrieving some kind of user input. The next example asks the user where he wants to go and modifies the link respectively.

```
javascript:(function(){var relPath=prompt('Where do you want to go?'); open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/" + relPath);})();
```

I tested this one in the current versions of Firefox and Chrome. Just add a new bookmark and use the JavaScript Code instead of any URL.

---

*Additional examples, as requested in comments.*
For the sake of readability, I present the second one in multiple lines, please remove the line breaks before trying to use it as a bookmarklet.

The first example navigates from
**protocol://sub.domain.tld/any/possible/path/somewhere.xyz** to 
**protocol://sub.domain.tld/web1/site/site.xml**.

```
javascript:(function(){open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/web1/site/site.xml");})();
```

The second example navigates from
**protocol://sub.domain.tld/keep/this/any/site.xml** to 
**protocol://sub.domain.tld/keep/this/another/resource**.

If `window.location` does not contain a long enough path name, the navigation will not work, because the script will just add "undefined" in the target URL.

```
javascript:(function(){
    var pathNameAsArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var pathToKeep = "/" + pathNameAsArray[1] + "/" + pathNameAsArray[2];
    open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + pathToKeep + "/another/resource");})();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! May you help me, if it is possible this?:

When I am on page 

www.example.com/web/site/site.xml

and want to go to the page

www.example.com/web/settings

is it possible to do it with javascript? Need the same javascript for more pages ...like

www.example.com/web1/site/site.xml
www.example.com/web1/site/site.xml
...

Thank you very well! Adam

Comment: I think the second example does what you want. Does it?